# Compute the following integral of the Heaviside step function

Tags: integration, step-function

I wish to compute the integral $$\int_{-t}^tH(x+1) \, dx$$ where $t \ge 0$ and $H$ is the Heaviside step function, i.e., $$H(x)=\begin{cases} 1, & \text{if } \quad x>0 \\ 0, & \text{if } \quad x<0\end{cases}.$$

I think the best way to approach this is to divide the interval $[-t,t]$ into subintervals so that I can use the definition of $H(x+1)$. I'm not sure exactly how to do this though.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a graph as an aid? It makes it simple. I think answer is $2t $ for $t \le 1$ and $t+1$ for $t>1$ is it right?

Comment: By graph I mean a rough sketch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the correct path. Observe that there can be $2$ cases:

1. $t>1$

In this case, using $z=x+1$, the integral can be divided as
$$\int_{-t}^tH(x+1) \, dx$$
$$=\int_{-t}^{-1} H(x+1) \, dx+\int_{-1}^tH(x+1) \, dx$$
$$=\int_{-t+1}^{0} H(z) \, dz+\int_{0}^tH(t+11) \, dz$$
$$=\int_{-t+1}^{0} 0\cdot \, dz+\int_{0}^{t+1} 1\cdot \, dz$$
$$=0+t+1$$
$$=t+1$$

2. $t<1$

In this case, using $z=x+1$, the integral need not be divided; rather written as
$$\int_{-t}^tH(x+1) \, dx$$
$$\int_{-t+1}^{t+1} H(z) \, dz$$
$$=\int_{1-t}^{1+t} 1\cdot \, dz$$
$$=2t$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Notice that both solutions can be expressed compactly as $$2t-(t-1)H(t-1)$$